# C# Excel COM Interop: Spawning Too Many Processes

Tags: c#, excel, interop, com-interop

I have written a winform app that outputs to an Excel file.  I am failing to properly clean up afterwards, however, since I always end up with way too many Excel processes running.  Here is the creation and destruction code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
...
wb.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Regards.

Comment: Have you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513319/c-sharp-why-are-excel-processes-not-ending)?

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks.  I did read those posts before I asked.  I don't seem to have "Marshal" as an option.  I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Do I need to include another library?